# Make MS Entourage forget old e-mail addresses

Tags: email, entourage

From time to time, coworkers send messages from their personal e-mail accounts. Entourage likes to store and suggest these addresses when composing messages in the future. This is great, except that it inevitably leads to work-related messages being sent to personal addresses. Is there any way to either disable this behavior (only suggest LDAP-linked addresses?) or flush Entourage's memory of this

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [entourage.mvps.org](http://www.entourage.mvps.org/glossary/mru.html):

> Entourage X, 2004 and 2008: To clear
>   ALL there is a preference in Mail &
>   News: Compose: Clear List button.
>   There is also an option in the
>   preferences to disable this feature
>   all together.
>
> To clear a single address, add it
>   exactly like the one that is
>   remembered to your address book and
>   mark it as Junk (or assign category
>   Junk). You can just delete the
>   address, but if you receive it again
>   it will just be added back. Marking as
>   junk will permanently remove it from
>   the AutoComplete list.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a Mac here to verify this, but it looks like the database for nicknames is stored here:

~/Documents/Microsoft User Data/Office 2004 Identities/[name of your
identity; typically "Main Identity"], where "~" represents your home
directory.

I don't know about only forcing it to suggest LDAP-only addresses, but this should allow you to edit the nicknames in there.